# Why can't I open a custom web.config file in my web ASP app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I can't open a web.config file in my ASP web project.

I can add config files in my project for set the authorization pages.

I need to open these pages to be able to update the "Roles" names from my admin page.

After following the sample from Microsoft, it should be working normally:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4c2kcht0(v=vs.100).aspx

**Here is the C# code I use :**

```
//Open the web.config custom
Configuration config  = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/WebAuthorizationPilotageGeneral") as Configuration;

//Get the authorization section

// section is always == NULL !!!!

-> section = (System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationSection)config.GetSection("authorization");

//Remove all Roles before add news Roles
section.Rules.Clear();
autho = new System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule(System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow);
foreach (string role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
{
     if (role != ttbx_RoleName.Text)
     {
          autho.Roles.Add(role);
     }
}

//Add the news Roles
section.Rules.Add(autho);
//Save the web.config custom
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
```

**My web.config custom file I try to load to update "authorization" section**

```
<!-- WebAuthorizationPilotageGeneral.config - access pilotage page -->
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Administrator" />
  <allow roles="Audit" />
  <allow roles="Copil" />
  <allow roles="System" />
  <allow roles="User" />
  <allow roles="visitor" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

**The weird things is after load the config file, my config object still have 22 sections, and should have only one => "authorization" , it's look like my (web.config) root file and not the (WebAuthorizationPilotageGeneral) config file.**

[image]

**UPDATE : I try to put my 4 config files on only one folder**
[image]

**Web.config file**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MS examples, there is used relative config path without "~" symbol. Have you tried to remove it?

```
// Set the root path of the Web application that contains the
// Web.config file that you want to access.
string configPath = "/MyAppRoot";

// Get the configuration object to access the related Web.config file.
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);
```

Comment: yes sorry , i just try again now with "/WebAuthorizationPilotageGeneral" , but still same result ..

Comment: So I believe you use it wrong way. They say "Set the root path of the Web application that contains the Web.config file that you want to access." Try to move your config file to new subfolder, call it web.config and your path set to '/subfolder'. I think now it's loading your full web.config.

Comment: Ok , i got it. So i put all my web.config files in a folder. And load with ('/Authorization') , like on the picture i just add now on the description. But still same result .. I think maybe we should only put one web.config file by folder . The problem is all my webpages are in the root app

Comment: Yes, i believe so. It always load file name "web.config". So you need to put your authorization config to different folder/subfolder and call it web.config. But leave the 'full' webconfig where it is, in the root. Hope it'll work.

Comment: Finally i change my logic, like you advise me . Thanks for everything ^^